# How to add truncatechars filter in Django form&

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I need to add truncatechars filter to Django template (in ul), but ul rendering in form.

Here is my form:

```
class TranslatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
    )
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
    )
    specializations = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=True,
        choices=Specialisation.objects.all().values_list("id", "title"),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        label=_("specializations"),
    )
```

Template:

```
<div class="line _dj_multicheckbox">
    <label for="pe_{{ form.specializations.name }}">{{ form.specializations.label }}</label>
    {{ form.specializations }}
    {% include 'profiles/snippets/errors_snipet.html' with field=form.specializations %}
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Some specializations have too much symbols, so I need truncatechars here.
Is there a way to do this in from? Like Widget or something?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but from the question I do understand that in your rendered html template, your "specializations" have too many characters and you want to shorten them. A simple fix would be to use some CSS. Add either an ID or a Class name to your specializations and then use https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow this as reference on how to "cut-off" the extra characters. I hope this helps you out!

I still do not have the reputation to post comments so I am sorry that I am giving this as an answer rather than a comment!